# Not enough margin between votes and question title in Hot Meta Posts

Tags: bug, user-interface, community-bulletin

Just noticed that there's not margin between the number of votes and the question title in Hot Meta Posts if the question has more than 99 votes. Currently, it looks like the number is part of the question title for the third question.

[image: screenshot of Hot Meta Posts]

Comment: Lots of dupes exist for this one, but alas, no fixes for it since it was first reported 2 years ago (?) unfortunately.